# Android Studio: Virtual machine acceleration is out-of-date

Tags: android-studio, haxm

Android Studio shows "Virtual machine acceleration driver is out-of-date", even though I just installed the latest version of haxm from github.
Does anyone know how to fix that?

I tried to install it with Android Studio, but it keeps getting errors.

Comment: I fixed it with just installing an older version... the latest isn't working for now I guess

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Answer (score 6):

I recently got this error too and I made this to solve it.

1. Go to turn windows features on or off
2. Turn on virtual machine platform
3. That's how it worked for me, hope you

Answer (score 4):

There are a few things you can try to fix this issue:

1. Make sure that you have installed the correct version of the HAXM
   driver for your system. You can download the latest version from the
   Intel website or from the Android Studio SDK Manager.
2. Check if virtualization is enabled in your BIOS settings. You can
   access the BIOS settings by restarting your computer and pressing
   the key specified on your screen (usually F2 or Delete).
3. Try uninstalling and then reinstalling HAXM from the Android Studio
   SDK Manager.
4. Try disabling Hyper-V if it is enabled on your system. You can do
   this by going to Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on
   or off, and then unchecking the box next to Hyper-V.
5. If none of the above solutions work, try creating a new virtual
   device with a different system image.

Hopefully one of these solutions will work for you.

Comment: #2 worked for me, I have a custom built computer and my virtualization was off by default. After turning it on the emulators started without the HAXM out-of-date error.

Comment: #2 worked for me too, thanks @abdul

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 7. Before installing Android Studio make sure:

1. You have installed Windows 7 Pro or Ultimate licenced or pre-activated version.
   !!!No cracked trial!!! Activators may interfere with Android Studio installation;
2. Make sure you disabled Driver Signature Check (for me worked only with "gpedit");
3. Make sure you have fast Internet;
   4.(optional) Better have SSD instead of HDD

Having performed those conditions I installed AS with HAXM and other stuff from scratch pretty easy on the first try. (Well...before that I made almost a hundred tries and almost lost hope XD)

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 11 I was able fix it by activating Hyper-V platform and virtual machine platform in Windows features.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Switch on Virtual Machine Platform checkbox in Control Panel > Programs > Turn Windows features on or off > Virtual Machine Platform.

This should work!

Answer (score 1):

If Hyper- v is not enabled in the control panel (Programs ->Turn Windows features on or off), enable it and restart your computer. This worked for me.